# Exceptions on the Command Line Python OS Module

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I'm currently messing around with the OS Module in Python, and what I want to do, is catch exceptions on the command line, and raise them as well.

```
command = input("Enter a command:")
os.system(command)
except:............How do I do this?
```

Let's say the user enters an invalid command, such as 'foo'. How can I catch the exception?

Comment: You really should be using `subprocess` rather than `os.system`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, no exception is thrown. You might be able to determine the error by the return code of the shell or the command, which is returned by os.system()

```
>>> os.system('foo')
sh: foo: not found
32512
```

Note that the second line is not the output of python.

Comment: How do I get the return code, when I enter foo, all that prints out is:
foo
sh: foo: command not found

Comment: @user1247509: returncode = os.system('foo'); if returncode != 0: print('ERROR: invalid command'); #0 is normal exit status, anything alse is an error